# How to count elapsed time on Python

Tags: python

I have the following code:

```
def base(nomor)
    day = localtime.tm_wday
    time = localtime.tm_hour
    no = str(nomor)
    dosen = cek_dosen(no)
    if dosen == 'null':
        no_dosen()
    elif dosen != 'null':
        ada_dosen()
        matkul = cek_jadwal(day,time,dosen)
        if matkul == 'null':
            no_jadwal()
        elif matkul != 'null':
            ada_jadwal()
            pertemuan = cek_pertemuan(matkul)
            print pertemuan
            if pertemuan > 1:
                cek_before(pertemuan)
                filename = ''.join([dosen, matkul, str(pertemuan), ".pptx"])
            else:
                filename = ''.join([dosen, matkul, str(pertemuan), ".pptx"])
            grabfile(filename)
            os.system(''.join(["loimpress ",filename]))
            pertemuan = pertemuan + 1
            update_pertemuan(pertemuan,matkul)


    mulai()


if __name__ == '__main__':
  mulai()
  while True: 
    data = port.read()
    count += 1
    if count == 1:
        if str(data) != start:
            nomor = ''
            count = 0
    elif 2 <= count <= 13:
        nomor = nomor + str(data)
    elif count == 16 and str(data) == stop:
        base(nomor)
        nomor = ''
        count = 0
```

I want to count time elapse from after `data = port.read()` until after `grabfile(filename)`.  I've used `start = time.time()` after `data = port.read` and `end = time.time()` after `grabfile`, `time = end - start`, but it stuck after `data = port.read()` so I use Ctrl + C to stop that. If I put `start = time.time()` after `no = str(nomor)`, I get `Attribute Error : 'int' object has no attribute 'time'`.

How do I count the elapsed time?

Comment: You can't use the variable name `time` because that is the name of the time module. Your example int eh description will work as long as you use a different variable name.

Comment: can u help me to correct my code? what i should add and where to add? really do not understand how to use it

Comment: You're going to need to split your code into smaller functions. Its super hared to follow and I have no idea what you are doing, so I can't help much. Look at DeepSpace's answer. Put the `start` before the function call you want to time and the print statement after.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow!  Please [edit] your question with an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org).  This will help you get better answers more quickly.

Comment: SSCCE is also known as [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: Yeah I just had SSCCE in my canned comments.  I'll update it.

Comment: @brandaemon Thanks for reviewing my question, i will use sscce next time

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Summarized:**

```
import datetime

if __name__ == "__main__":
    d1 = datetime.datetime.now()
    data = port.read()
    # Do more things ...
    tdelta = datetime.datetime.now() - d1
    print(tdelta.total_seconds()) # This is your answer
```

Comment: i need to count the elapsed time after the data = port.read(), not before. can i put this code after data = port.read()?

Answer (score 1):

```
from time import clock

start = clock()
...
print "Time taken = %.5f" % (clock() - start)
```

Comment: my program still stuck after data = port.read(), i use ctrl + c to stop it. why it always like that if i put start = clock() after data = port.read()

Comment: Perhaps it's reading while in a loop and doesn't know when to stop reading. Post your port.read() code or tell us what library it's a part of.

Comment: i forget that i have use start to check the str(data). ive use another variable, but it has the following error : AttributeError: 'int' object has no attribute 'clock'

Answer (score -1):

Take a look at the python [**timeit** module](https://docs.python.org/2/library/timeit.html).

Basic example:

```
>>> import timeit
>>> timeit.timeit('"-".join(str(n) for n in range(100))', number=10000)
```

Comment: This isn't really what he's looking for.